# List just the names of files that contain a string in Linux

Tags: linux

I want to list just the names of files that contain a string using Linux commands.

When using egrep, all the instances of the string are shown, which could be multiples times.

**For example:**

```
egrep disco music_file*.txt
```

**Might show;**

```
music_file1.txt: blah blah blah disco stuff

music_file1.txt: disco blah blah blah

music_file1.txt: I like to listen to italodisco

music_file2.txt: I like to party to disco

music_file3.txt: Does your dog like disco?
```

**Whereas all I want is :**

```
music_file1.txt

music_file2.txt

music_file3.txt
```

**Question:** *How can I just show one instance of each file name when searching for a string in Linux?*

Comment: This is probably better off on the linux exchange, unless you are looking to write a program that does this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `-l` to your egrep expression:

```
egrep -l disco music_file*.txt
```

From `man grep`:

> -l, --files-with-matches
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from
> which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop
> on the first match.  (-l is specified by POSIX.)

Answer (score 4):

grep -l should work for you.

```
  grep -l pattern files*.txt
```

From man page:

```
      -l, --files-with-matches
          Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print the name of each input
          file from which output would normally have  been  printed.   The
          scanning  will  stop  on  the  first match.  (-l is specified by
          POSIX.)
```